# Why is こと written in katakana in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances

I was reading a webtoon and came across this sentence:

> 傷つきそうなコト言わないでね

I'm aware of the meaning of this sentence, but I'm confused as to why it uses katakana here.  I know that katakana is sometimes used to indicate that the speaker is a foreigner, but this isn't the case for the character saying this line, so I have to admit I'm a little befuddled.

Edit: I just had an idea, could it be that this indicates that the speaker is speaking a strange voice?

Comment: any context? A screenshot of the webtoon would help. There are a lot of reasons it might be written in katakana, and it's hard to know which one if we have no information.

Comment: Note that hiragana or katakana might be used simply to make a word more explicitly visible.  Japanese has no whitespace usually, so long strings of just-hiragana or just-katakana can blend together visually and become harder to read.  Changing "case" can differentiate words and make it easier for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

「事」looks more formal, so I'd assume it's in katakana to make the word sound more casual. I'd have to have more context to know for sure, though.